# Multiple Super Munchkin Cards

Tags: munchkin

If I have 2 Super Munchkin or Half Breed (or any equivalent) cards, am I able to use up to 4 races/classes (Or 2 races/classes without any race/class related penalties)? Effectively, do these bonuses stack, or can you only ever have 2 races and 2 classes?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can only have two.

Super Munchkin says:

> You may have two Class cards...

Half Breed says:

> You may have two Race cards...

So that's exactly what you can do: have two. It doesn't matter how many of them you have. All they say you can do is have two. They don't say "one additional" or "twice as many".

Comment: Too bad... I liked being a warrior, wizard, cleric, and thief all at once! Thanks though!

Answer (score 7):

The Super Munchkin card only allows you to have two Class cards in play;  ... however the [***Ultra Munchkin***](http://www.worldofmunchkin.com/cards/ultramunchkin/) card from the [Munchkin Rigged Demo](http://www.worldofmunchkin.com/riggeddemo/) and [Munchkin 7 - Cheat With Both Hands](http://www.worldofmunchkin.com/cwbh/) sets states:

### **Official Rules**

> You may have three Class cards, and have all the advantages and disadvantages of each.

[image]

Comment: The Munchkin 7 expansion ([either](http://www.worldofmunchkin.com/moregoodcards/cards.html) [version](http://www.worldofmunchkin.com/cwbh/cards.html)) also includes the even better ***Super Duper Munchkin***, which lets you use *any number* of Class cards. And, of course, ***1/3-Breed*** and ***Chimera***, which do the same thing for Race cards.